# How do you customize VS 2019 Breakpoint window toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints

I want to add *Disable All Breakpoints* to the VS2019 Breakpoints window toolbar.  How do I do that?

Comment: Its already there, black/white circles icon.  If you meant something else then use Help > Send Feedback to ask them to update the Tools > Customize > Commands > Toolbar feature.

Comment: That's to do the selected one.  There is a separate command that is two white circle icons for disabling all.  You can see them both in the Debug menu.  But for some reason, the Breakpoints window toolbar only has the one.

Comment: @HansPassant Are implying that users CANNOT update the Breakpoint Window toolbar?  If that's true, please answer so others will know they need to Send Feedback (the more that point out the need, the better chance it will be implemented).